Vue 2 + swiper, Why does using swiper.slideToLoop(index) scroll to the beginning or to the end?
Currently, when the last slide is active, I call the method swiper.slideToLoop(index) where the index can be 0, 1, or 2. Both sliders scroll to the desired indices, but they go through all the slides, not by the shortest path.
It was expected that using swiper.slideToLoop(index) would transition immediately (for example, from the last slide to the first or vice versa from the first to the last).
Without using thumbs
private get swiperOptions1() {
  return {
    swiperKey: `swiper-${this.swiperUniqueId}`,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 4,
    overflow: true,
    threshold: 20,
    navigation: {
       nextEl: `.swiper-btn-next-${this.swiperUniqueId}`,
       prevEl: `.swiper-btn-prev-${this.swiperUniqueId}`
   
       }
  }
}

private get swiperOptions2() {
  return {
     swiperKey: `swiper-thumbs-${this.swiperUniqueId}`,
     loop: true,
     slidesPerView: 3,
     centeredSlides: true,
     spaceBetween: 4,
     loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
     navigation: {
        nextEl: `.swiper-thumbs-btn-next-${this.swiperUniqueId}`,
        prevEl: `.swiper-thumbs-btn-prev-${this.swiperUniqueId}`
     },
     breakpoints: {
       650: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 20,
     },
  }
}


// 2 methods responsible for control 

private onChangeSlide() {        
  if (!this.swiper1) return

  const activeSlideIndex = this.swiper1.$swiper.realIndex
        
  this.swiper2.$swiper.slideToLoop(activeSlideIndex)
}

private onChangeThubmSlider() {
   if (!this.swiper1 || !this.swiper2) return
   const index = this.swiper2.$swiper.realIndex
   const indexSlide = this.list.findIndex(({sort})=> sort === index)

   this.swiper1.$swiper.slideToLoop(indexSlide)
}

И сам слайдеры
<Swiper
  :options="swiperOptions1"
  :key="swiperOptions1.swiperKey"
  ref="swiper1"
  @slideChange="onChangeSlide"
>
  <SwiperSlide  v-for="slide in list" :key="slide.id">
    <!-- slide --> 
  </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>

<Swiper
  :options="swiperOptions2"
  :key="swiperOptions2.swiperKey"
  ref="swiper2"
  @slideChange="onChangeThubmSlider"
>
  <SwiperSlide  v-for="slide in Twolist" :key="slide.id">
    <!-- slide --> 
  </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>

The first slide differs in that a couple of extra blocks are added to it, but otherwise they are identical. When the first slide reaches the extra blocks, the second one remains unchanged, and then they should move synchronously again

Why it happens this way is due to the opinion of the Swiper developers wanting it to be this way.  Unfortunately it can't be helped.  You would need to bring this to their attention (à la github issue) for functionality to be changed.

Perhaps you can create workaround using repeated calls of slideNext() or slidePrev() based on shortest distance between current and desired index.
